# On Click event on a links but one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem that has just come to light on my gallery page.
I have JavaScript to take care of user menu selection but one of the options is to return back to the home page but it's not working as the On Click event takes over all a links on page, is there a way around this? i have searched the net for an answer but no luck, Thanks.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  LoadGallery($('a[data-albumid]:first').data('albumid'));
  $("a").click(function() {
    var dir_path = $(this).data("albumid");
    LoadGallery(dir_path);
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="#" id="here">Gallery</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" data-albumid="images/gallery/fld01/">2014</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-albumid="images/gallery/fld02/">2014</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-albumid="images/gallery/fld03/">2014</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-albumid="images/gallery/fld04/">2015</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-albumid="images/gallery/fld05/">2015</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="index.html" id="home">Back to home</a></li>
  <!-- This one never works! -->
</ul>
```

Comment: `< script type = "text/javascript" >` is invalid HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are giving `return false` on **all** the links, which makes your other "normal" links not work. You can do `:not` operator:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  LoadGallery($('a[data-albumid]:first').data('albumid'));
  $("a:not(#home)").click(function() {
    var dir_path = $(this).data("albumid");
    LoadGallery(dir_path);
    return false;
  });
});
```

Or just bind the event only to `href=#`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  LoadGallery($('a[data-albumid]:first').data('albumid'));
  $('a[href="#"]').click(function() {
    var dir_path = $(this).data("albumid");
    LoadGallery(dir_path);
    return false;
  });
});
```

So that it doesn't affect the other links.

Comment: Thank you for that, never found that with Google.

Comment: Er... That would be there, but anyway, welcome and all the best @Dave.

Comment: Merry Christmas and a happy new year.

Comment: @Dave Same to you! `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Give a class to the links that you want to behave the same way:

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="#" id="here">Gallery</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="mylink" data-albumid="images/gallery/fld01/">2014</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="mylink" data-albumid="images/gallery/fld02/">2014</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="mylink" data-albumid="images/gallery/fld03/">2014</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="mylink" data-albumid="images/gallery/fld04/">2015</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="mylink" data-albumid="images/gallery/fld05/">2015</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="index.html" id="home">Back to home</a></li>
</ul>
```

And then change your event binding like this:

```
 $(".mylink").click(function() { // do what you want here }
```

It's cleaner and uses classes right to their purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to `unbind` the click event for the that single `<a>` tag,

```
$( 'a[href="index.html"]').unbind( "click" )
```